# How to Use Jquery Datatables in Ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js, datatables, ember-data, ember-cli, ember.js-2

I picked up learning **emberJS** lately and I have had issues doing some basic things I would have done while not using this framework. The main issues I have had was using **jquery plugins**, in this case jquery **datatables**

**in my component's component.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(model){
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(model) {
            this.$(".datatables").DataTable();
        });
    }
});
```

**in my component's template.hbs**

```
<table class="table table-hover datatables">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each courses as |course|}}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ course.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ course.title }} </td>
            <td  class="text-center"> {{#link-to 'courses.edit' course }} Edit {{/link-to}} </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**then i used the component like :- **

```
{{#course-datatable courses=model}}{{/course-datatable}}
```

*I would appreciate a demo accompanied with answers.*

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i haven't done a component of the jquery datatable plugin. But yes for other Jquery plugins, it would be more or less like this. If you are building your own component: 
Add the Datatable js files to include inside your BrocFile

Run in ember client

```
ember g my-jquery-datatable
```

this will generate the component in the generated hbs fill in the general html you would use

```
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>

                </tr>
         </thead>
    {{#each modelWithData}}
    <tr>
    <td>this.name</td>
    <td>this.position</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

then on you js generated file initiate the plugin in the didInsertElementMethod

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement(){
       this.$('#example').DataTable();
}
});
```

then to be able to use this table in other components or controllers you can do

```
{{my-jquery-datatable modelWithData=otherArrayWithTheTableAttributes}}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey @Sudakatux! Thanks for swift response. I had this already, So the problem with this is  that data tables says** no data in the table and the count reads 0 out of 0 entries**

Comment: Do you have a populated array in your ```otherArrayWithTheTableAttributes```? If you hardcode table data does it work?

Comment: if hardocoding works and the array is populated, then I guess your each is not iterating, try not initializing the datatable to check if the table gets populated with the array.

Comment: The each was iterating. At first it would load up the data but I tested by using the search that comes with datatables, then all the data disappears.

Comment: ok you dont need this ```{{#course-datatable courses=model}}{{/course-datatable}}``` since you got rid of ```yield``` you can do ```{{course-datatable courses=model}}``` i dont understand what you mean with   " it would load up the data but I tested by using the search that comes with datatables, then all the data disappears. "  you mean in the jqueryDataTable or just the table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94864/discussion-between-riliwanrabo-and-sudakatux).